# Getting error while Send Fileupload and JsonData object to dotnet core api using axios

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios

**This is My Code**
**From axios**

```
 onPublishChannelHandler = async () => {
 const request = { ...this.state.channel };

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('images', request.images[0]);
request.images = [];
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(request));

const result = await axios.post(
  'http://localhost:50634/api/user',
  formData,
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  }
);
```

}

**At Dotnetcore API**
**My Model**

```
    public List<IFormFile> images { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPhoto { get; set; }
    public bool AgreedToTermsAndCondition { get; set; }
    public string CreatorType { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

**API**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] ChannelSaveRequest request)
```

When i post from axios i only get file and other Fields getting null

Comment: Hi @Tejas, any updates about this case?

Comment: @FeiHan Yes its working, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i post from axios i only get file and other Fields getting null

Based on your `ChannelSaveRequest` model class, to make it work well, please modify your formData object as below on your JavaScript client side.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('images', request.images[0]);

formData.append('SelectedPhoto', request.SelectedPhoto);
formData.append('AgreedToTermsAndCondition', request.AgreedToTermsAndCondition);
formData.append('CreatorType', request.CreatorType);
formData.append('MobileNo', request.MobileNo);
formData.append('Email', request.Email);
```

Besides, if you do not want to change client side code, you need to implement a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample) like below.

```
public class CSRequestModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // ...
        // implement it based on your actual requirement
        // code logic here
        // ...

        var model = new ChannelSaveRequest();

        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("data").FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ChannelSaveRequest>(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("data").FirstOrDefault());

            model.images.Add(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0]);
        }


        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

*Apply it on action parameter*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm][ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CSRequestModelBinder))]ChannelSaveRequest request)
{
```

Test Result

[image]